# Will `sufficient` override `requisite`?

Tags: pam

I just read the [`pam.d` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d). It states:

> **required:** failure of such a PAM will ultimately lead to the PAM-API returning failure [...]

and

> **requisite**: like *required*, [...]

and

> **sufficient**: success of such a module is enough to satisfy the authentication requirements of the stack of modules (if a prior required module has failed the success of this one is ignored).

. The description of *sufficient* doesn't state that it will also be ignored for prior failed *requisite*s. Will it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requisite` immediately returns to the app (or to the superstack) on failure. As such, a subsequent `sufficient` isn't even processed if a prior `requisite` failed.

> **requisite**: like required, however, in the case that such a module returns a
>              failure, control is directly returned to the application or to the
>              superior PAM stack.